# How can I return a object with the sum of all objects from a list using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a list of an object called Spendline with two properties, Year and Amount and BudgetID. How can I best convert the following List:

```
Year      Amount      BudgetID
2000      100         1
2001      100         1
2002      100         1
2003      100         1
2001      100         2
2002      100         2
2003      100         2
```

To this:

```
Year      Amount      
2000      100         
2001      200         
2002      200       
2003      200
```

Using Linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) and [Sum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/538fac10-6f62-478c-98bc-6f9765872e67/) functions

An example of getting this data with a loop might look like this:

```
foreach(var group in SpendlineList.GroupBy(x => x.Year))
{
   int year = group.Key;
   int ammount = group.Sum(x => x.Ammount);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want something like:

```
var query = items.GroupBy(x => x.Year, x => x.Amount)
                 .Select(g => new { Year = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum() };
```

Or as a query expression:

```
var query = from item in items
            group item.Amount by item.Year into g
            select new { Year = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum() };
```

(Call `ToList` on the query to get a `List<T>` of course.)